# Is there a way to force an update to the eclipse workspace?

Tags: eclipse, eclipse-rcp

I am preparing a release of my RCP product which will use an updated eclipse platform. It is distributed as a packaged setup.exe and, when installed, is set up to use a standard workspace location. The first time it is run, the users will be warned that the workspace was written with an older version.

As a large proportion of my users are not very tech-savvy, they will not know what a workspace is or what to do with the warning. Many will call the IT Hotline.

I want to avoid this message and force the acceptance of the update of the workspace without any warnings.

Is there a way to suppress this message?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming you are using the standard Eclipse Application the version check is done by `org.eclipse.ui.internal.ide.application.IDEApplication` in the `checkValidWorkspace` method.

This is an internal class so you are not really supposed to extend it. If you decide to ignore that you could define your own application specifying a class that extends `IDEApplication` and uses a different `checkValidWorkspace`

Answer (score 0):

I added the following to `plugin_customization.ini`:

```
org.eclipse.ui.ide/WARN_ABOUT_WORKSPACE_INCOMPATIBILITY=false;
```

The workspace checks are done but no warning is displayed and avoids extending the internal class mentioned by greg-449.